# How to customize kubeconfig server IP in k3s

Tags: k3s

I used the following command to install K3s

```
$ export INSTALL_K3S_EXEC="--docker --write-kubeconfig ~/.kube/config --write-kubeconfig-mode 666"
$ curl -sfL https://docs.rancher.cn/k3s/k3s-install.sh | INSTALL_K3S_MIRROR=cn sh -
```

When viewing kubeconfig after successful installation, it was found that the server IP used was **127.0.0.1**

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx==
    server: https://127.0.0.1:6443
  name: default
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: default
    user: default
  name: default
current-context: default
kind: Config
```

I would expect cluster's serverIP to be the **host IP:6443** instead of **127.0.0.1:6443**, which would facilitate its `remote use`.

How do I set up startup?

I would appreciate it if you could tell me how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

We cannot override loopback IP while installing K3s. Because it has hardcoded in K3s source [code](https://github.com/rancher/k3s/blob/master/pkg/daemons/control/server.go#L50).

```
localhostIP        = net.ParseIP("127.0.0.1")
```

Comment: I've just looked at the --bind-address in [server-config/#listeners](https://rancher.com/docs/k3s/latest/en/installation/install-options/server-config/#listeners) and tested it, which can modify the server IP. whether the modification of this parameter will cause an error?

Comment: is it modifying IP address in kubeconfig file? @moluzhui

Comment: Yes, after `INSTALL_K3S_EXEC` added `-- binds-address MyHostIP`, and then installed k3s by shell script, I ran the `cat $HOME/.kube/config` command to see that the `cluster server` had changed to `https://MyHostIP:6443`. But I'm not sure if that's going to cause any other problems. @hariK

Comment: I don't think it'll cause any problems. It just binds the server to given IP. @moluzhui

Answer (score -1):

every time you change the IP loopback to your host address, it would be back to IP loopback 127.0.0.1 when you restart your K3S or K3S service or reboot your machine.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).